# making process run in background with execvp

Tags: c

i want to make a child process run in background using fork and execvp, i saw many same questions but for some reason none of them really ment run in background.
when i mean i want the program to run in background i mean i dont want to see it at all. currently i have a program called e_print whuch prints output every 1 second, i want to keep it running but not see the output (really run in background)
here my code:

```
        if((son = fork())==0){//son process
        i = execvp(tokens_set[0],tokens_set);//tokens set was previously set
        if(i == (-1)){
            perror("couldn't find the command: ");
        }
        exit(0);

    }else{ // father process
        printf("father proccess goes on\n");
    }
```

for some reason all the guides and questions i saw called it run in background but the childs output was seen.

i want to keep the father running, say ask for another input from user and meanwhile i want the e_print process to run.
same as:

```
./e_print &
```

from terminal.

Comment: Does the "child process" output to the console? Running in the background with `&` would not stop that either.

Comment: @crashmstr you are right, for some reason i thought it will not print to the terminal.

Comment: @crashmstr so how i can know if the son process runs in background instead of switch turns with father process?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and daemonize the child process. Not sure if this is really what you want.

Comment: hi, whats exactly daemonize? i want to be able to make any process run in background

Comment: Long story short, in general, you detach the child from it's parent so that the child's parent will become the init, and close all file descriptors. If you want, for example, the children to do it's job, and also the parent to do it's own job, without caring what the child does ( not waiting for it) and without the system getting clogged with zombie processes, you have to double fork.

Hope this link will explain better than I do: http://www-theorie.physik.unizh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't got anything to do with the actuall fork or execvp calls, it's got to do with how you wait for them.

For a foreground process like I assume you have been dealing with so far you will fork the new process, run a program with exec, and then wait for the child in the parent with wait() or waitpid(). If a process is foreground or background only depends on where and how you wait for the child. You could also install a signal handler to communicate with the children

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is about the output then what you do is close and reopen the child program's standard output to /dev/null.

In your "son" process before calling execvp, do:

```
close(0);
close(1);
close(2);
open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
```

Of course in a real program you should always check return codes.